# Is it forbidden to sleep in a bed where a husband and wife usually sleep?

Tags: halacha, sleep, midas-chasidus

The [Nitei Gavriel 51:6](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pagepngs/46544_334_964_0.png) writes that it is a *midas chasidus* (pious trait) not to even look at a married couple’s bed. So maybe actually sleeping in their bed would be an outright *issur* (prohibition).

Is it forbidden to sleep in a bed where a husband and wife usually sleep?  If so, does anyone permit it?

Comment: Welcome John. Your question might get better answers if you gave some background. What made you think this might be a problem?

Comment: @JohnSmith please [edit] your clarification into the question so people can look at the question and understand the full context

Comment: The one place that sorta deals with this is brought by the Mechaber in OC (note it doesn't make it into EH) אכסנאי אסור לשמש ואם יחדו לו ולאשתו בית מותר ובלבד שלא יישן בטליתו של בעל הבית ,there is no mention of such a din that you mentioned

Comment: @sam are you sure it's the same issue?

Comment: of course not - only if the bed is assur b'hana such as hekdish or worshipped as avodah zarah

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the background.

The objective of the Raishis Chochmo is because looking at a marital bed of people he recognises is likely to cause licentious thoughts to arise:

להסכתל במטה שאיש ואשתו ישנים בה אם מכירן כי זה יעורר תאות היצר יותר ויותר

Your question then will turn on whether sleeping in the bed, alone or with one's wife will have the same effect.

Your assumption does however seem reasonable based on the footnote (10), where he writes that he has seen that careful people (medakdekim) would not even allow a child into a room specially set aside for husband and wife.

The question is whether we can develop a formal issur from middas chassidus and what the medakdekim do. But until we CYLOR, it's better to be careful.